# What is the correct way to subscribe to a websocket from a Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to subscribe to a websocket from my Rails server so that every time a message is received I can create a background job.

`Faye::WebSocket::Client` seems to do the trick but i'm not sure where to put it (thread, separate process?). Ideally i would like to keep sending (to create new subscriptions) to this websocket from the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create it as a service and then run it either with a rake task, cron or simply when the server starts.
Than you could monitor it with tools like monit to make sure it's allways ON.